# Asp.Net dynamic controls postback

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls, postback

I have an asp page where controls are dynamically added from the DB on Page_Init()
The EnableViewState is set to false.

One of the dynamic controls is a CheckBox and when checked it causes postback.

Now on Page_Init I repopulate my page (after changing according to rules) and the checkbox's checked property is now false.

It stays false up to the end of LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() from what I can see.

```
protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
{
    Control cntrl = Page.FindControl("FINS10CopyAddress");
    Boolean check = ((CheckBox)cntrl).Checked;
    return null;
}
```

Then suddenly its true again on OnPreLoad().

```
 protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
    Control cntrl = Page.FindControl("FINS10CopyAddress");
    Boolean check = ((CheckBox)cntrl).Checked;
    }
```

If I do the same with another control's visible property it works.

Any ideas what can cause this or suggested methods to override to not load previous state ?

The Answer below helped me to create a workaround:

```
dataValue cntrl = ((Helper)Session["helper"]).Event.Control(Request["__EVENTTARGET"]);
if (cntrl != null)
{
    if (cntrl is webCheckBox)
        ((CheckBox)Page.FindControl(Request["__EVENTTARGET"])).Checked = (Boolean)cntrl.Value;
}
```

Comment: This sounds exactly like viewstate is populating your control. Have you checked your viewstate object in debug mode to make sure the viewstate is not loaded?

Comment: ViewState.Count = 0 in both methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

It is the postback data setting the control, in your `LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()` see:

```
var val = Request[Request["__EVENTTARGET"]];
```

Unfortunately the Request object is readonly

I don't know of any other way to stop it from setting the value to what it was changed to on the client side except to set the value to what you want it in `LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()` after the `postbackdata` has been set.

Comment: Request cant be assigned to as its readonly. But yes 

    Request["__EVENTTARGET"] contains the checkbox's name

Comment: Sorry, it should be Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"], changed in code. Basically what's happening here is that the value of the checkbox is transferred from client side and then loaded there

Comment: Wow, I'm still fast asleep, it is: Request[Request["__EVENTTARGET"]] that will give you the value

Comment: Well I managed to use your answer to create a workaround so thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad i was able to help, I've spent a lot of frustrating hours on this in the past :-)